# Getting an error when running xamarin project?

Tags: xamarin.android

I am new in xamarin, create a sample application using xamarin android native, when try to run get an error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo -prop monodroid.avdname=Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo

PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
Emulator Android_Accelerated_x86_Oreo cannot be started.
Runtime checks completed
Build has been canceled.
```

Comment: Hi , having a look at this document [Managing Virtual Devices with the Android Device Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/device-manager?tabs=macos&pivots=windows). If not finding the reason , you can show a screenshot of the interface Device Manager .

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio go to Tools -> Android -> Android SDK Manager
Then make sure Android 8.0 / 8.1 (whichever one you're targeting) is installed.

Next in Visual Studio go to Tools -> Options -> Xamarin -> Android Settings
Then make sure you have the appropriate paths specified in Java Development Kid Location and Android SDK Location (should see little green checkmarks).

Also check the box to "Auto Install Android SDKs".

If something is screwed up still, would recommend going to Visual Studio Updater, then confirming Xamarin workload is installed or try to repair.